# Rsync Error 23: Can I tell which files were not transferred?

Tags: rsync

I ran `sudo rsync -va --progress` from the root of one external drive to a folder on another external drive. The reason is that the source drive has an error-ful NTFS and I don't have access to a Windows PC to repair the NTFS.

10 hours later it said:

```
sent 608725204596 bytes  received 19365712 bytes  15902210.53 bytes/sec
total size is 608586212274  speedup is 1.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
```

I saved the entire terminal output. At the beginning, there are a few hundred `Input/output error (5)` for files I actually don't need totaling roughly 2GB. OSX Finder "disk usage" tells me the source is 617 billion bytes, not 608 as in the above report.

Questions:

1. Does the first portion of the verbose output (building a file list) definitely say `Input/output error (5)` for EVERY file that won't be copied?
2. Does `code 23` mean that all the files except the `Input/output error (5)` ones were successfully copied?

Comment: Possibly helpful: rsync error messages appear to start with "rsync: ", so `grep '^rsync: ' output` may be helpful.

Answer (score 32):

`23` only means (from the man page):

> 23     Partial transfer due to error

For everything that could not be transferred, you'll get an error message. Note that the error messages could be about opening or reading directories, so you won't necessarily see an error message for each file that could not be transferred.

If your source has not changed, you can run the `rsync` again with `-n` to see what it would transfer this time without actually doing the transfer.

About the byte difference, `rsync` gives you the size of the files (how much data can be read from them). Are you sure `Finder` doesn't tell you the *disk usage* instead?

Also note that NTFS can store data in alternate *streams* or attributes of the files, and `rsync` will typically not transfer (is not aware of) those (and that can account for a lot as well).

Comment: So are you saying that ALL of the data (no matter how corrupted) that was not transferred was listed at the beginning as a `Input/output error (5)`?

Comment: regarding byte difference: Yes that is correct. I'm confused though about why the difference between rsync's report and Finder's "disk usage" is 9 billion bytes but I can only identify 2-3 billion bytes of files that said `Input/output error (5)`. Can you explain?

Comment: @themirror, a 1-byte file will still need a few kilo-bytes allocated on disk to store it (try `echo > file; du -k file` to see how much on the source filesystem, but on ntfs, it's usually 4k). `rsync` will tell you that the size is `1`, but Finder might tell you 4096 for that file.

Comment: @themirror, wrt your first comment, I'm saying that for everything (file content, see my edit about alternate streams) that could not be transferred, you'll get an error, but if you get a _can't read directory /foo_, then obviously `/foo/bar` and `/foo/bar/baz` won't have been transferred either.

Answer (score 27):

You can silence rsync's non-error output using rsync's `-q` flag.

```
-q, --quiet                 suppress non-error messages
```

If you run rsync again with the `-q` flag, rsync will likely still fail, but at least this time any error messages that are causing your problem will not be buried under lines and lines of file transfer status messages.

Answer (score 8):

Re: error 23-- The most common reason to have this error is to make a minor typo entering in the rsync source. Look over your source command and make sure everything checks out against ls, and look for stupid subtle things like an extra space or a 1-l problem.

Comment: I know it is silly, but I even went the route to keep digging through the code until I realized I had made this dumb mistake. Thank you!

Comment: What is a 1-l problem?

Comment: A 1-l problem is when you can't distinguish between similar looking characters due to the font used. "1," "l," "I," and "|" are among those commonly confused, as are "0" and "O."

Comment: in my case, my external drive is unmounted. And after mounting it again, I still got the error 23. I ended up deleting all partially transferred from last attempt. And `rsync -n` this time won't give me that error anymore